# When does ajaxError get called if using $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I put this in my JavaScript, and introduced a 500 error in my $.ajax, but this routine never got called:

```
$('#msg').ajaxError(function(myEvent, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    $(this).html(thrownError).addClass('alert alert-error');
});
```

If I add a .fail, then the .fail get's called, but the ajaxError is never being invoked.

Comment: `ajaxError` Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/ they have several examples

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX request is even going through? Use Firebug to check.

Comment: Yeah.  Hmmmm... I wonder why it's not working...

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, ajaxStart IS being called, but ajaxError is not.

Comment: Are you sure it's not actually getting called? I introduced a 500 error, but it just turns out that `thrownError` is an empty string; the other parameters are populated (as expected) when debugging via console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajaxError() besides others are Global events and you will use these events whenever you have standard way of handling ALL ajax requests on you site ,instead of per ajax request. E.g showing some progress bar on success/failure ..

[Jquery ajax global events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

In above case , make sure your script fails to check the ajaxError e.g by requesting a invalid url etc .. Or Server responding invalid data

Comment: That's true.  But ajaxError isn't being invoked, and I have an error that isn't being caught by anything already.  It's a proof-of-concept page to see how ajaxError works.

Comment: make sure you are adding this method before you make ajax request

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the document selector like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError
```

Comment: For reference: "As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxError() method should only be attached to document." [.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)